# Approximate value for the area between the curve

Tags: programming, numerical-integration

I've got this task:

> Use *Mathematica* to obtain an approximate value for the area between
>   the curve $y=1/4$ and the x-axis over the interval $[1,2]$ with $50$
>   subintervals using the left endpoint, midpoint and right endpoint
>   approximations. Note: the entire calculation needs to be shown in
>   *Mathematica*.

Here's what I've tried:

```
a = 1; b = 2; n = 20; 
Ln = (b - a[f)/n*Sum[f[a + (i - 1) (b - a) / n], {i, 1, n}]
LeftSum[f_, a_, b_, n_] := (b - a)/n* Sum[f[a + (i - 1) (b - a)/n], {i, 1, n}]
f[x_] := 1/xLeft = N[LeftSum[f, 1, 2, 20]]
```

Comment: a = 1;
   b = 2;
   n = 20;
   Ln = (b - a[f)/n*Sum[f[a + (i - 1) (b - a) / n], {i, 1, n}]

Comment: LeftSum[f_, a_, b_, n_] := (b = a)/n*
  Sum[f[a + (i - 1) (b - a)/n], {i, 1, n}]

Comment: Clear[f]f[x_] := 1/xLeft = N[LeftSum[f, 1, 2, 20]]

Comment: how can you please show me

Comment: 2 - (3771059091081773 f)/5342931457063200   is this the output

Answer (score 12):

I'll change your proposed function because it's a constant and for such a function all sums will be equal.So:

```
f[x_] := 1/4 x^2
di = (2 - 1)/50;
intervals = Range[1, 2, di];

leftSum =   Sum[f[i] di,        {i, Most@intervals}];
rightSum =  Sum[f[i] di,        {i, Rest@intervals}];
middleSum = Sum[f[i + di/2] di, {i, Most@intervals}];

exact = Integrate[f@x, {x, 1, 2}];
N@{leftSum, rightSum, middleSum, exact}

(*{0.57585, 0.59085, 0.583325, 0.583333}*)
```

**Edit**

`NIntegrate[]` already provides the Left and Right Riemann sums:

```
Quiet@NIntegrate[f@x, {x, 1, 2}, Method ->{"RiemannRule", "Type"-> #, "Points"-> 25}, 
                 MaxRecursion -> 0] & /@ {"Left", "Right"}

(* {0.57585, 0.59085}*)
```

You could verify that these Riemann sums are the same that we calculated earlier by doing:

```
pts = Rationalize@First@Last@Reap@Quiet@
        NIntegrate[f@x, {x, 1, 2}, 
                   Method -> {"RiemannRule", "Type" -> #, "Points" -> 25}, 
         MaxRecursion -> 0, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x]] & /@ {"Left", "Right"}

Complement[intervals, #] & /@ pts
(*{{2}, {1}}*)
```

So showing that the last or first point are excluded depending on the type of sum.

**Edit**

```
Framed@GraphicsRow[Plot[f[x], {x, 1, 1.25}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
     Epilog -> {Opacity[.5], Blue, EdgeForm[Darker@Blue], 
       Rectangle @@@ (Transpose /@ Transpose[{Partition[intervals, 2, 1], 
       Partition[Riffle[f /@ #@intervals, 0, {1, -2, 2}], 2]}])}] & /@ 
                                        {Most, Rest,MovingAverage[#, 2] &}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Pending upvote (could you produce some output ?)

Comment: @eldo Since the function proposed by the OP is constant, all Riemann sums are equal. I didn't include the numerical results because I thought they could bring some confusion.

Comment: @eldo Done. Perhaps I found a way to alleviate the confusion.

Comment: Now I can see. Unfortunately, I can't upvote twice :)

Answer (score 6):

```
f[x_] := 1/4
int = N@FindDivisions[{1, 2}, 50];
dx = int[[2]] - int[[1]];
```

Then:

```
leftSum = Total[f[#] dx & /@ Most[int]]
rightSum = Total[f[#] dx & /@ Rest[int]]
middleSum = Total[f[# + dx/2] dx & /@ Most@int]
```