# Trapezoid approximation to definite integral

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, numerical-integration

This question is related to
[Graphically approximating the area under a curve as a sum of rectangular regions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82688/82691?noredirect=1#comment223414_82691).

I now was trying to adapt the code by MarcoB to get the approximation of the integral by trapezoids, and I used the function `Line`. I only need to color the trapezoids now. Is it possible to adapt the following code to do that?
Thank you

```
f[x_] = Sin[x]
Manipulate[
 lines = Table[ {Blue, 
    Line[{{a + i (b - a)/n, 
       f[a + i (b - a)/n]}, {a + (i + 1) (b - a)/n, 
       f[a + (i + 1) (b - a)/n]}}] }, {i, 0, n - 1, 1}];
 Show[{Plot[f[x], {x, a, b},  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], Graphics[{Thick, lines}]},
  ImageSize -> Large],

 {{a, 0}, -10, 10},
 {{b, 6}, -10, 10},
 {{n, 15} , 1, 40, 1}
 ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I could hardly be expected to resist...

Rather than using `Line` objects, it would seem more natural to use `Polygon` objects (see [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Polygon.html)). In the spirit of [my suggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/82691/27951) to your previous question, I am leaving the simple rectangle approximation in the code as well, as an option to the `Manipulate`:

```
f[x_] := Sin[x]
Manipulate[

 polygons = {

   Table[{Opacity[0.05], EdgeForm[Gray], 
     Rectangle[
       {a + i (b - a)/n, 0}, 
       {a + (i + 1) (b - a)/n, f[a + i (b - a)/n]}
     ]},
    {i, 0, n - 1, 1}
   ],

   Table[{Opacity[0.05], EdgeForm[Gray], 
     Polygon[{
       {a + i (b - a)/n, 0},
       {a + i (b - a)/n, f[a + i (b - a)/n]},
       {a + (i + 1) (b - a)/n, f[a + (i + 1) (b - a)/n]},
       {a + (i + 1) (b - a)/n, 0}
       }]
      },
     {i, 0, n - 1, 1}]
   };

 Show[{
   Plot[f[x], {x, a, b}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}],
   Graphics[ polygons[[type]] ]
  },
  ImageSize -> Large
 ],
 {{a, -1}, -10, 10},
 {{b, 6}, -10, 10},
 {{n, 5}, 1, 40, 1},
 {{type, 2, "polygon\ntype"}, {1 -> "left rectangles", 2 -> "trapezoids"}}
]
```

[image: Manipulate for trapezoid integral estimation]

Comment: If one just wants the outlines of the polygons, it is a simple matter of inserting `Directive[FaceForm[None], EdgeForm[Black]]` in the appropriate spot.

Comment: Do we have a question about Lebesgue integrals coming up too? :-)

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I think I'd call myself out of that one though. I just barely understand the concept of Lebesgue integration, and that's on a good day! :-)

Comment: Thank you! Before getting to Lebesgue there is approximation by Parabolas for Simpson's method! ahah