# How do I divide an integral into parts and sum the total?

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have an exercise looking like this: Analyze the integral $4\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1-x^2} \, \mathrm{d} x$ numerically by deviding the interval ${]0,1[}$ into three equal parts, then summarize the integral parts.

I just can't get it to work. I tried to make tables, sum functions, Integrate functions but i can just make it the normal way like this: `Integrate[4 (Sqrt[(1 - x^2)]), {x, 0, 1}]`.

Any help

Comment: Also I don't want to coyp-paste because the next thing is to divide it into 100 parts which i can't just copy paste 100 times...

Comment: Depending on what you mean exactly by your question, you may also be interested in [Graphically approximating the area under a curve as a sum of rectangular regions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82688/27951) and [Trapezoid approximation to definite integral](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82782/27951).

Answer (score 4):

Create a function that returns a list of adjacent intervals in $[0,1]$:

```
ClearAll[intervals]
intervals[n_] := Partition[Subdivide[0, 1, n], 2, 1]
```

For instance:

```
intervals[3]
```

[image: intervals]

Then numerically integrate your function over all those intervals:

```
partials = NIntegrate[4 (Sqrt[(1 - x^2)]), {x, #1, #2}] & @@@ intervals[3]

(* {1.30821, 1.14505, 0.688329} *)
```

The total is $\pi$, as should be from the overall integral:

```
Total[partials]
(* Out: 3.14159 *)
```

You can now divide the range up into however many subintervals:

```
NIntegrate[4 (Sqrt[(1 - x^2)]), {x, #1, #2}] & @@@ intervals[15]
```

> {0.266469, 0.26528, 0.262885, 0.259252, 0.254327, 0.248033, 0.240262, 0.230864, 0.219631, 0.206261, 0.190302, 0.171025, 0.147111, 0.115629, 0.0642622}

and of course the sum is still the same.

---

Note that I am using numerical integration here (i.e. [`NIntegrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html)) because the symbolic integration can be quite slow even for a simple function. If you want analytical results, use `Integrate` instead, but beware of long execution times!

```
symbolic = Integrate[4 (Sqrt[(1 - x^2)]), {x, #1, #2}] & @@@ intervals[3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and the total is $\pi$ as expected, after some simplification:

```
Simplify@Total[symbolic]

(* Out: π *)
```