# Computing integral using trapezoid method and simpsons' rule for a given partition

Tags: integral-equations

I am given `f[x_]=E(x^-x)-1` on interval `[1,4]` and partition `1<1.5<2<2.5<3<3.5<4` and want to compute the integral of my function using both trapezoid and simpson's rule for this given partition.
Here is what I have been given for trapezoid rule and simpsons rule but I am having trouble understanding where to apply my partitions for both methods.
Trapezoid rule:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
trap[f_, a_, b_, n_] := 
 Module[{h = (b - a)/n, vals}, 
  vals = Map[f, Table[a + i h, {i, 0, n}]];
  N[h Plus @@ vals - h/2 (First[vals] + Last[vals])]]
f[x_] = x E^-x - 1;
trap[f, 0, 4, 7]
```

Simpson's rule:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
simp[f_, a_, b_, n_] := 
  Module[{h = (b - a)/(2 n), vals, coeffs}, 
   vals = Map[f, Table[a + i h, {i, 0, 2 n}]];
   coeffs = Table[3 - (-1)^i, {i, 0, 2 n}];
   coeffs[[1]] = 1; coeffs[[2 n + 1]] = 1;
   N[h/3 Dot[coeffs, vals], 15]];
f[x_] = x E^-x - 1;
simp[f, 1, 4, 7]
```

Comment: Would this help? [Trapezoid approximation to definite integral](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82782/27951)