# Riemann sum with table of rectangles. rectangles not inside the plot graph

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, animation, homework

I was doing an assignment for a class in which I have to do an animation of the Riemann sum and how the area changes as the rectangles divide. So far I have the following but there is a problem with the graphs, as stated in the title I cant get the rectangles to show inside the graph.

[image]

Comment: You need to put the `Show` inside the `Animate`. Also it's good practice to post *code* not pictures. Use the formatting buttons inside the "Ask a Question" pane.

Comment: Thank you very much! Also sorry for the image :( this is the first time I post but its a good thing that I now know about it!

Comment: Have you seen [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82688)?

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_] := x^2;

a = -3;
b = 6;

m[n_] := (b - a)/n;

R[r_] := Table[
    {Opacity[0.2], FaceForm[Black], 
      Rectangle[{a + (m[r]*(i - 1)), 0}, {a + (m[r]*(i)), f[a + (m[r]*(i))]}]}
    , {i, r}
  ]

Animate[
 Show[{Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 6}], Graphics[R[c]]}, PlotRange -> All]
 , {c, 1, 100}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]